# Web Server Becomes Unresponsive - What now

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, web-server, web

Im running a VPS with Windows 2008r2 DataCenter, 1 CPU and 2GB RAM.

At apparently random intervals the server becomes unresponsive in that I cant access certain websites it hosts - yet others seem to work. I also cant RDP in to the box, nor can I interact with it via the providers VPS Management console.

I have to get them to reboot it for me so that it becomes operational again.

The server is running a Developer edition of SQL2012(sp1), latest MySQL, a wordpress site via IIS(which becomes unresponsive), a .Net site(which seems to work), a simple php site and a mail server(SmarterMail by SmarterTools).

Typically it is using about 1.8GB of RAM and about 20-40% CPU load.

Ive asked my providers about this and they say they want paying $100ph to investigate regardless of whos fault it is.

So, what can I do from my end of things to try and find out as much as possible about the source of the issue? Please bare in mind that this is the first server Ive had, so whilst Im really keen to learn how to do things properly, I'd really appreciate pointers and help going in the right direction....

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously a -1 yet no response as to why? Whats so wrong with this question? If you think its invalid, why not get off your high horse or at least stoop a little to my level and explain why its stupid!!! Minus 1ing without a reason is just lame.

Comment: If you can't get your provider to check for problems that are their fault without paying them for it, you need to change providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be different issues, (check your logs as MDMarra suggests), 1 CPU and 2 GB ram when is WAY too few resources. Especially since you are running already at 1.8 GB (which probably means the other 200 MB is reserved for the operating system). If I were you I'd increase your resources by at least adding another 2 GB of memory and maybe an extra cpu.

Then benchmark your machine to test it against peak moments and see if  you have enough resources to cope with that influx.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am already considering upping the ram a bit, but cost is a bit of an issue. At present the sites on there are really low traffic so wouldnt expect them to put any significant load on the system. In terms of benchmarking, do you have any recommendations for methods / tools?

Answer (score 2):

Fire up perfmon and look at the event logs when the server hangs. Those two things should be your starting point. Most likely you have a resource problem, but perfmon will confirm that.

Comment: Will the logs need setting up to monitor various elements or will they be doing this already? Any specific logs worth looking at? Anything in particular you recommend looking out for? Thanks for the response! ;-)

Comment: Event logs will show system or application failures. Perfmon is for monitoring performance and has *excellent* documentation. TechNet is your friend.